# Insert values into a Matrix under adjacency constraint

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I created this matrix:

`latticeJ = ConstantArray[5, {20, 20}];`

and I want to randomly replace 20 values of this matrix with the value of 10 under the condition that none of the 20 newly replaced values are adjacent to one another.

I tried things like:

`ReplacePart[latticeJ, 
 Flatten[RandomChoice[latticeJ[[]]]] -> 20]`

but to no avail.

Comment: "with the value of 10" and `-> 20` contradict.

Comment: To my knowalge there is no built in function, which would implement "none of the newly replaced values are adjacent to one another". You need to come up with the algrithm to do that I am afraid.

Comment: How difficult would it to be to implement this algorithm? How can I randomly replace 20 of the values in this matrix with a specific number? I can start there.

Comment: Your "adjacency constraint" is actually equivalent to the [Queens Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), only that you don't have queens but kings (it depends if you are regarding a 4- or 8-neighbourhood). That means, that you can start placing 10s into your matrix, but when you hit a dead end and you cannot insert another 10, you need to backtrack. So it's not done (if you want to do it non-hacky) by simply replacing randomly. Assume you want to replace (20*20)/2 positions. There are only 2 solutions for a 4-neighborhood and searching randomly would be insane.

Comment: As for your simplified question, try `ReplacePart[latticeJ, RandomChoice[Tuples[Range[20], 2], 10] -> X]`

Comment: Thank you @halirutan. That worked. I was looking into sparse arrays and tuples, but didn't the tuples part together.

I was looking into the queen problem you mentioned. There are also Kings ones, but I guess I am "playing" on 20x20 board.

Comment: @halirutan How could I conditionally (and randomly) replace 20 of the fives so that that none of them are to the left, right, up, or down of eachother? Maybe I will just suffice with them being diagonal.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't matter if you have a 20x20 matrix or a 100x100, in its essence, it is similar to the queens' problem. If you want to search randomly, then create a function `check` that tests if all randomly selected positions are separated and go on drawing random positions until you find a combination, that meets the requirement. However, as I said, that's far from clever or optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
df = ChessboardDistance;
minDistance = 1;
n = 20;
parts = {RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]};
While[Length[parts] < n, ri = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]; 
 If[Min[df[ri, #] & /@ parts] > minDistance, AppendTo[parts, ri]]]

latticeJ2 = MapAt[10 &, latticeJ, parts];
(* or latticeJ2 = ReplacePart[latticeJ, parts -> 10]; *)
latticeJ2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Counts[Flatten@latticeJ2]
```

> <|5 -> 380, 10 -> 20|>

With `n = 75`, `latticeJ2` becomes:

[image]

```
Counts[Flatten@latticeJ2]
```

> <|10 -> 75, 5 -> 325|>

Needless to say, the task is impossible for large enough `n`.

Comment: Thank you, @kglr. This is fantastic!

Comment: @kglr Do you use your `i=1` statement anywhere?

Comment: Thank you @ThatGravityGuy; it is leftover from previous edits.

Answer (score 4):

**Loop method**

```
Block[
    {reps = DeleteDuplicates@RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {19, 2}]},
    While[
        Length[reps] < 20,
        AppendTo[reps, RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]];
        reps = Cases[
            {#, Nearest[Complement[reps, {#}], #, {All, 1}, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]} & /@ reps,
            {pt_, {}} :> pt
            ]
    ];
    reps
];
Length@%
ReplacePart[ConstantArray[5, {20, 20}], %% -> 10]//MatrixForm
```

> 20

[image]

Where the `ChessboardDistance` does *not* allow for diagonally adjacent elements, and if you just get rid of the `DistanceFunction` option, then it uses the Euclidean metric, which *does* allow diagonal adjacency because then the elements are $\sqrt{2}$ away from each other.

**Recursive method**

```
RandMat2[reps_List] := If[
    Length@reps < 20,
    RandMat2@With[
        {rando = Append[reps, RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]]},
        Cases[
            {#, Nearest[Complement[rando, {#}], #, {All, 1}]} & /@ rando,
            {pt_, {}} :> pt
        ]
    ],
    reps
]
ReplacePart[ConstantArray[5, {20, 20}], RandMat2[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {19, 2}]] -> 10] // MatrixForm
```

**General recursive method**

Well, mostly general.  This method is only valid using `ChessboardDistance`, since that is what allows for the restriction `0 < n <= If[EvenQ@Dim, Dim^2/4, (Dim + 1)^2/4]`, which tells us the maximum number of choices we could have for any dimension, from the [Kings Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KingsProblem.html).

```
RandMat[Dim_Integer, n_Integer, rad_?NumericQ, reps_: {}] /; 0 < n <= If[EvenQ@Dim, Dim^2/4, (Dim + 1)^2/4] := If[
Length@reps < n,
RandMat[Dim, n, rad, #] &@With[
    {rando = DeleteCases[Union[reps, {RandomInteger[{1, Dim}, 2]}], {}]},
    Cases[
        {#, Nearest[rando, #, {All, rad}, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]} & /@ rando,
        {x_, {x_}} :> x
    ]
],
reps
]

MatrixForm@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], RandMat[2, 1, 1] -> 1]
MatrixForm@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], RandMat[3, 2, 1] -> 1]
MatrixForm@ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}], RandMat[5, 4, 2] -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in ways already indicated. I want to point out that, if there is a need to scale to larger matrices and/or more alterations, there are a couple of approaches that might be more efficient. I will show one such since it is easier to code. The idea is that after each new random position is selected, we mark its neighbors as "off limits" so that we get a quick predicate for determining when to discard a selection.

I only show how to select positions, since the subsequent alteration step is immediate. For simplicity I assume that the matrix is square, but extending to general rectangular is not difficult.

There is one catch. We might get into a situation where there are no viable positions remaining. I do not actually check for this, instead using an arbitrary cap on the number of attempts as `n^2`, where `n` is the requested number of positions (I am not assuming it is necessarily equal to the dimension).

As second efficiency is to fill in a preallocated array with newly selected positions. One could instead use `Reap/Sow`. `AppendTo` scales quite poorly and should be avoided if size requirements grow.

```
randomPosns[dim_, n_] := Module[
  {picked, tot, posns, count = 0, pos, nbhood, j = 0},
  tot = dim^2;
  posns = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, n];
  nbhood = Map[IntegerDigits[#, 3, 2] - 1 &, Range[0, 8]];
  While[count < n && j < n^2,
   j++;
   pos = RandomInteger[{1, dim}, 2];
   If[picked[pos], Continue[]];
   count++;
   posns[[count]] = pos;
   Scan[(picked[#] = True) &, Map[pos + # &, nbhood]];
   ];
  {j, count, posns}
  ]
```

Here we use dimensions from `n=64` up to 2^10, doubling size at each step, and selecting `n*CubeRoot[n]` positions. I show timings, then a list of the form {number attempts, number positions obtained}. The former, for this count, is never much larger than the latter so there are not too many attempts that fail due to collision with a prior selection or neighbor thereof.

```
result = 
  Table[Timing[randomPosns[n, Floor[CubeRoot[n]*n]]], {n, 
    2^Range[6, 10]}];
result[[All, 1]]
result[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]

(* Out[27]= {0.03125, 0.09375, 0.265625, 0.671875, 1.71875}

Out[28]= {{369, 256}, {794, 645}, {1835, 1625}, {4402, 4096}, {10850, 
  10321}} *)
```

In cases where the number required might approach the limit of what can be selected subject to the neighbor restrictions, there is a faster method based on a standard approach to uniform shuffling. It takes a bit more code though. (A further advantage is it does not require down values, hence can coded using `Compile` should absolute speed be a need.)